# "Belongs on another site" doesn't allow any other site

Tags: bug, close-reasons

I just tried to vote [a question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75062/is-ignatius-claim-that-christians-didnt-keep-the-sabbath-correctly-translated) for closing:

```
Close
    → A community-specific reason
        → This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network
            → belongs on hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com
```

The only choice offered for another site was the site it's already on.

Shouldn't it instead say "Christianity.SE"?

Even if not, a menu that leads people to a dead-end is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

We would have to request that staff add that site as a migration target. I'm not sure it would be worth it, we don't really migrate that many questions. In the last 90 days we've migrated three questions to Christianity.SE, one question to Judaism.SE, and one question to Latin.SE. These are very small numbers and easily handled by mods doing the migrations themselves.

In any case, until such a time that we do request it, if we ever do, please write a custom flag requesting a migration. Then the mods can move these questions.

Comment: Whether it should be there is a policy question; not for me to decide.
But that the menu leads people to a dead-end is an implementation bug.

Comment: It's not a complete dead end, because migrations to Meta do happen.